# Redirecting Batch Script Output to Shared Folder in Network

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, batch-processing

I am using Anaconda Environment for running Python 3.6 (Windows 7) . I have a Windows Batch Script (.bat) for running scripts which I have written in python . The output of the batch script is 3 CSV files which are currently stored in the same directory as the python script.

I want to store the CSV files in a shared network location ; but I don't know how . Can we do that ?

```
conda activate env_name
python script.py
```

This is what I am using currently to run the batch script. Also I want to schedule this Batch script in Windows machine to run everyday at 12:00 am JST. Any help in that direction is appreciated .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Windows has had a task scheduler built into the operating system for darn near forever. I don't see any code that shows how those csv files are being created, so I would assume they are being created by the python script. So you would need to edit that code.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and got the above code working . Just gave the UNC address in the `open()` command in my python script and it started writing to that network location .

As for the Task Scheduler , created a .bat file with the following 1 line code :

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\script.py
```

And posted to the scheduler.

Thanks for the help !